# Products are not adding to the cart in Magento 2

Tags: cart, magento-2.1, catalog

In list page I have created the only two **add to cart** buttons instead of every product and created the **Qty** textbox for every product. When customer entered the `Qty` hit the `Add to Cart` button I am adding the products to cart. So for this I am trying to add products to cart in my custom module and it's added to cart but not showing in my cart. When ever I refreshed the page showing messages this product added to cart like this. And one more thing is after added products it's not refreshed the page automatically.

For this I have written below code.

**root/app/code/Test/CustomCart/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

```
 <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'addtocart/index/index'; ?>" method="post">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <button type="submit"
                            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                            class="action tocart primary">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                    </button>
            </div>
            <!--End the Custom Button-->
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
................
core code
.....................
</form>
```

**root/app/code/Test/CustomCart/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\CustomCart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;


    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;


    protected $_urlInterface;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,CustomerCart $cart,\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|void
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl());

        try{


            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $sku_list = [];

            foreach($request as $k => $v){
                if (strpos($k, 'qty_') !== false) {
                    $sku = explode('_',$k);
                    if($v !="" || $v !=0)
                        $sku_list[$sku[1]] = $v;
                }
            }

            $product = $this->_productFactory->create();

            foreach($sku_list as $k => $v){
                $data = $product->loadByAttribute('sku',$k);
                $product = $this->_initProduct($data->getId());

                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }

                $params = array('product' => $product->getId(),'qty' => $v);
                $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                $this->cart->save();

                $message = __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.',$product->getName());
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

            }

            return $resultRedirect;

        }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $cartUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl();
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($cartUrl);
            }

            return $resultRedirect;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }


    }


    protected function _initProduct($productId)
    {
        if ($productId) {
            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

[image]

could you please guide me how can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this by removing the `$this->cart->save();` from `foreach` and pasted the outside of `foreach` loop.

```
/**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|void
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl());

        try{


            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $sku_list = [];

            foreach($request as $k => $v){
                if (strpos($k, 'qty_') !== false) {
                    $sku = explode('_',$k);
                    if($v !="" || $v !=0)
                        $sku_list[$sku[1]] = $v;
                }
            }

            $product = $this->_productFactory->create();

            foreach($sku_list as $k => $v){
                $data = $product->loadByAttribute('sku',$k);
                $product = $this->_initProduct($data->getId());

                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }

                $params = array('product' => $product->getId(),'qty' => $v);
                $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$params);


                $message = __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.',$product->getName());
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

            }
            $this->cart->save();
            return $resultRedirect;

        }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $cartUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl();
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($cartUrl);
            }

            return $resultRedirect;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }


    }
```